# MySQL how to fetch data from multiple table and insert into other?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 database and I want to fetch data from 2 db and insert into another 1 but I have some problems doing it.

**Database1 'first' : Table 'items':**

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Crystal | 30 |
| 2 | Ruby | 20 |

**Database 2 'second' : Table 'Shop':**

| id | name | items_id | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KK shop | 1 | NY |
| 2 | ABC Supermarket | 2 | AL |

I need to fetch data from table Items and search then 'name' in table Shop by using the 'id' from table Items.
Then I want to insert the data into table Details.

This is how it show look like, from empty to this:

**Database 3 'third' : Table 'Details':**

| id | items.id | items.name | shop.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Crystal | KK shop |
| 2 | 2 | Ruby | ABC Supermarket |

**My questions :**

1)Since I have 3 database how should I connect to all of them in the same time? Should I create 3 php file to connect each of them and then include 3 of them in the same file?

2)If I want to copy all columns from a table to another table can I do like this? Will this copy all columns from 'first.items' to 'third.details'?

```
SELECT * from first.items
INSERT INTO third.details;
```

3)My SQL query,

```
SELECT * FROM first.items, 
SELECT name FROM second.shop 
WHERE first.items.id = 1, 
INSERT INTO third.details (id,items.id,items.name,shop.name) 
VALUES (1,first.items.id,first.items.name,second.shop.name);
```

After executing the query my table Details is unable to get any data, what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You appear to just be generating redundant data.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "is unable to get any data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to insert into some table data selected from other tables you can use next approach:

- first: build query that select data that should be inserted. In your case in can be next:

  ```sql
  SELECT 1, items.id, items.name, shop.name
  FROM first.items
  JOIN second.shop ON shop.id = items.id
  WHERE items.id = 1;
  ```
- second: combine the query with `INSERT` statement like:

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO third.details (id, items_id, items_name, shop_name) 
  SELECT 1, items.id, items.name, shop.name
  FROM first.items
  JOIN second.shop ON shop.id = items.id
  WHERE items.id = 1;
  ```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

rename column :  Database 2 'second' : Table 'Shop':
items.id to **item_id**

Database 3 'third' : Table 'Details':Set id as auto increment

Use join to combine first two tables:

```
SELECT items.id,items.name,shop.name FROM shop as shop left join items as items on items.id = shop.item_id WHERE items.id = 1, 

INSERT INTO third.details (items.id,items.name,shop.name) 
VALUES (first.items.id,first.items.name,second.shop.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your INSERT INTO SELECT syntax is misplaced
2. In order to insert the entire table to the other one, the two must share compatible columns. Both counts and types.

The tables seem a bit unorganised but if you'd like to go through with it, the correct query should be as followed

```
INSERT INTO `third`.`Details` (`items.id`, `items.name`, `shop.name`)
SELECT  `second`.`Shop`.items_id, `first`.`items`.name, `second`.`Shop`.name
FROM `first`.`items`, `second`.`Shop`
WHERE `second`.`Shop`.id = 1 and `first`.`item`.id = 1;
```

Also changing the where clause to

```
 `second`.`Shop`.id = `first`.`items`.id;
```

should allow you to insert all the entries to your target table at once

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited the response just when you commented!

Comment: You haven't explained your query yet. How could anybody learn **why** your query wiorks better than the initial one?